# Wordpress, getting pages by tag

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I've used the functions file to enable pages to have tags so that I can build an elementor template that will be used for said pages.

My issue is that I'm trying to build a grid layout that will show page titles and featured images for all pages that have the tag 'Store Page'. I've cobbled together this code:

```
$args = array('post_type'=>'page', 'tag_id'=>3);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;
```

I'm not positive if this is what I want but it also broke my functions file resulting in the site being down until I fixed it via FTP.

I think the logic is right there, but I don't know if I have all the right args or not

Comment: This specific code wouldn't be placed in functions.php but instead one of the template files such as index.php, single.php or similar.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Good point, the reason I put it in functions is because it's inside of a function that places shortcode into elementor but I guess I could just do that through a template file

Comment: Oh, in that case it might be okay then. But whatever broke, with PHP and WordPress error reporting enabled you should have had an error message. Your code generally looks okay, I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong with it.